# How to use tf.slice on a tensor with unknown size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am dealing with a matrix, sim_mat, which is a tensor of size (?,?,?).

I want to use tf.slice on it like this:

```
a=tf.slice(sim_matrix,[0,0,0],tf.stack([tf.shape(sim_matrix[0],tf.shape(sim_matrix)[1],3]))
print(a)
```

But this gives me tensor a with size (?,?,?) instead of (?,?,3). Moreover, when I use a for further functions, I got an error message:

Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference, but saw value None.

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the following equivalent but more readable line with fancy indexing:

```
a = sim_matrix[ :, :, 0 : 3 ]
```

This will still give you a resulting tensor of shape ( ?, ?, ? ), however.

If you really need the resulting tensor's third dimension to be fixed, use [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather). You have to permute the dimensions with [`tf.transpose()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) before and after, however, because [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) only works on the first dimension. (There is [`tf.gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) too, but that's no help here, because you don't want to specify indices on the first two dims, you want to take slices.) So like this (tested code):

```
import tensorflow as tf

sim_matrix = tf.placeholder( shape=(None,None,None), dtype = tf.float32 )
sim_matrixT = tf.transpose( sim_matrix, [ 2, 0, 1 ] )
aT = tf.gather( sim_matrixT, [ 0, 1, 2 ] ) # get first three
a = tf.transpose( aT, [ 1, 2, 0 ] )

print( a.get_shape() )
```

Output:

> (?, ?, 3)

You also say you get an error on further functions. That still might be the case if those functions require fixed shape on their input tensor.

Comment: I have edited the question above, sorry for the confusion here. I believe the reason is not the way I write parameters in tf.slice() but the unknown dimensions in there. Is it possible to get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Rewrote answer in light of the clarification you posted

Comment: Thanks. It is really confusing which tf functions need fixed shape tensors and which do not.

Comment: Yes, it can be, unfortunately. I feel you pain. :) If you want help with that, I'd suggest you post another question with that topic. In the meantime, you could consider accepting my answer as I have answered the question posed here. :)